# Where are general questions about Myspace appropriate?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I asked this question ( https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/9845/new-myspace-do-you-have-to-be-member-to-view-others-profile ) on the Music Stack Exchange, but I feel it's not the right place.

Would this question fit [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)?

Are there any other SE sites where it would be more appropriate?

Comment: Definitely not [so]. That is not a technical question at all... I would have suggested their [help site](https://new.myspace.com/help) but that seems to be pointing right back to the login screen....

Comment: To closers: He's asking an on-topic question about where a question fits.

Comment: For the purpose of (our) learning: What makes you think that question might belong on [main]?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That question would be on topic for [Web Apps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/). ([FAQ](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq))